# How big is Snoke's command ship compared to a Super Star Destroyer?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*, it was shown that Snoke's command ship was very big. Its width seems to exceed the entire fleet under its command.

**How big was Snoke's ship compared to a Super Star Destroyer? Volume or surface area can be taken for comparison.**

Comment: It's probably about 1,000 LEGO pieces larger.

Comment: @Snow - I pity the poor sods whose kids want the Supremacy lego set for Christmas. It's as if millions of wallets suddenly cried out in terror, and were suddenly silenced.

Comment: @Valorum could be worse, they could be asking for the new millenium falcon

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A Super Star Destroyer like Vader's *Executor* is approximately 19,000m long and some 6000m wide and about 1500m deep.

By comparison, Snoke's mobile capital is 13,000m long, over 60,500m wide and more than 3000m deep.

[image]
<sub>Figures sourced from the [Star Wars Databank](https://web.archive.org/web/20140503100548/http://starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/technology/superstardestroyer/) and [The Last Jedi: The Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary)</sub>

Comment: Palpatine's Eclipse was 17.5 Km long. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eclipse_(Eclipse-class)

Comment: @Bat - That measurement is from Legends only. In the main canon there's no mention of its size, or really any other detail other than than that it's a Super Star Destroyer.

Comment: hmmm, so it is about half the width of the deathstar? ("The first Death Star was stated to be more than 100 km to 160 km in diameter, depending on source") https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Star. That's pretty big...

Comment: @Daniel - Half the *width*, but only a fraction of the total size.

Comment: What is the Finalizer?

Comment: @TylerH - That's Hux's flagship.

Comment: That's no B2 bomber, that's a space station...

Comment: Extrapolating from this data, I look forward to seeing the 180km-long Super-Super-Star-Destroyer in Episode 12.

Comment: What I want to know is how the First Order comes up with the cash to finance such a ship, without already being in complete control of the galaxy.

Comment: @whatsisname  - Merely being in control of half the galaxy isn't enough for you?

Comment: Now that's just silly.

Comment: @Devsman - Can you spend midi-chlorians?

Comment: @valorum they'll pay you to dispose of them. thats why the sith lords are so rich. They get payed to clean up Lucas's never-to-be-named abomination.

Comment: What about the Dreadnought?

Answer (score 3):

So the Mega class star destroyer has a width of 60km and a length of 13 km. The eclipse class(assuming that’s what was meant by Palpatine’s ship) has a length of 16 km. While the eclipse class is longer, the mega is far wider.